# Use of tags/shortcodes in Plone Document's text fields

Tags: plone

Is it possible to use something similar like metal-macros, or wordpress shortcodes, or jinja2 extension tags (or whatever other solution) inside the text field of a Document (or News Item)?

What I'm searching for is a way to do something like the following:

```
some text [mytag arg=red] some enclosed text [/mytag] some other text
```

and having a definition like for example:

```
def mytag(enclosed_text,arg):
    return '<div color="%s">%s</div>' % (enclosed_text,arg)
```

would return the following:

```
some text <div color="red">some enclosed text</div> some other text
```

Answer (score 1):

I know of no existing add-on that does just this. However, it's perfectly possible to create your own text transform add-on and hook it into the transformation chain. Martin Aspeli wrote a demonstration package (that's also very useful on its own) to show how to create custom transformations: http://plone.org/products/intelligenttext

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Adding a custom transformation seems a good idea. I'm currently evaluating http://plone.org/products/easy-template. It uses collective.templateengines combined with Jinja2. My idea at the moment is to write the tags as Jinja2 extensions. Nonetheless it sounds attractive to use standard fields and to parse and manipulate them in the tranformation chain. That way one could use existing pt-templates.

Comment: I need help on how to hook a transformation in the chain. I've opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/24222774/1659599