# How can I hook a transformation in the transformation chain?

Tags: plone

As far as I understand it, a transformation chain is filled with transforms after calculating the shortest path between original and target mimetypes (see `convertTo()` and `_findPath()` in `Products.PortalTransforms.TransformEngine`).

1. How can I hook a transformation in the transformation chain.
2. Are there maybe other means to hook a transformation?
3. If yes are there some example or documentation?

Comment: If your transform happens to involve HTML, `plone.outputfilters` offers another layer on top of `portal_transforms`. (BTW, the nitpicker in me would like to point out that there can be more than one shortest path, but since you're looked at the code, you're in a better position than I to know how that is handled.)

Comment: Thanks for the reference to `plone.outputfilters`. I've not yet found any useful documentation on how transforms and the transformation chain exactly work. Therefore I'm trying to find it out reading the sources. But thanks to your reference I've seen in the readme file that there are "transformation policies" which seem to act in this play.

Comment: BTW @UlrichSchwarz: nitpicking, though sometimes fastidious, is a useful practice when one wants to study how code works ;-). You're right there can be more than one path [in the set of] shortest path[s]! `_findPath` simply returns the first "shortest" path found. 

Furthermore `_findPath` do not exactly return a shortest path but it returns a path consisting of the prepended path of the `required_transforms` and the first shortest path found.

For now +1 to @UlrichSchwarz for answering my second question.